# Download full nuget package so I can copy to another machine?

Tags: package, build-process, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

### Background

I'm in a computing environment that utilizes Indirect Internet access (via a VM) for security.

I have the following machines:

- Desktop -- the machine I develop on; no internet access.
- Build Server -- hosts a local nuget feed. Also no internet access.
- Internet VM -- VM that has access to the internet. Files can be copied to my desktop.

### Question

Is there any way I can do the following:

- **On my internet VM, download a nuget package folder straight from the internet**

  - This is key and is the step I cannot seem to accomplish.
- Copy this folder to my build server's nuget directory
- Use the build server's feed from my dev machine to reference the package.

I can copy the folder right now, but only from my Dev environment, which would require me using nuget in my dev environment to download the package -- which I can't do, because the dev environment has no internet.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Is the internet VM in your setup allowed to act as server, e.g. can you install another private NuGet feed on it that acts as a proxy to the internet? Also, can you access the build server's NuGet package store directory from the internet VM via UNC path?

Comment: Unfortunately, the internet VM is destroyed after every use (security measure). The build server is also cut off from the internet. Local can access build, build can access local, but neither can access the internet. (as such, I have to be OK with a manual process).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [NuGet Package Explorer](http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases) to download packages the main NuGet feed in order to copy them over.

Alternatively, you could install an instance of [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget) on the internet VM, enable package caching on the default feed, then search/browse for a package and on its overview page select "Pull to ProGet" to put it in the feed's storage location. You can verify on the feed administration page where the packages are being stored, then copy them to wherever you want.

If you can access your build server from the internet VM via a UNC path (e.g. `\\build-server\c$\ci-tool\nuget-packages`), you can just set that as the feeds storage location and then any time you pull a package to ProGet it will automatically be available in your build tool's private NuGet feed.

Comment: Hi John -- one more curve ball: I can't install software on the Internet vm (it gets obliterated whenever I exit it and an entirely new machine is spun up). So I guess in my case, the question is, is there a web version of nuget package explorer where I can download the packages without needing VS? If no, I may have to build one..

Comment: No, NPE and ProGet both require installation. However, if you have access to a public server you could setup a public ProGet instance on a hosted server somewhere and browse to that from the internet VM.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to script it using the Nuget.Core API.
Quick steps to do so would be :
1. Create a project and install Nuget.Core nuget package in it.
2. This would add reference to Nuget.Core assembly. 
3. Write a quick method which would download package from the specified feed :

```
     static string feedUrl = "https://nuget.org/api/v2";
     string packagedir = string.Empty;
     PackageManager manager = null;

        IPackageRepository repo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository(feedUrl) as IPackageRepository;
        packagedir = Path.Combine(xxx);
        manager = new PackageManager(repo, packagedir);
       manager.InstallPackage(packageId);
```

This doesn't require any installations on your internet VM except .Net45